# For a non empty subset $S$ and a point $x$ in a connected metric space $d(X,d)$, let $d(x,S)$ = inf{$d(x,y): y \in S$}.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Note: This question is already exist (duplicate) on this site. But my approach is different.

For a non empty subset $S$ and a point $x$ in a connected metric space $d(X,d)$, let $d(x,S)$ = inf{$d(x,y): y \in S$}.

Which of the following statements is/are correct ?

1. If $S$ is closed and $d(x,S)>0$ then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$.
2. If $S$ is open and $d(x,S)>0$ then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$.
3. If $S$ is closed and $d(x,S)>0$ then $S$ does not contain $x$.
4. If $S$ is open and $d(x,S) = 0$ then $x \in S$

My Attempt:

Given that $d(x,S)$ = inf{$d(x,y): y \in S$}.By definition, If $x \in S$ then $d(x,S) = 0$ Also
$d(x,S) = 0$ iff $x \in \bar S$ If $S$ is closed then $S = \bar S \implies d(x,S) = 0$ then $x \in S$ if $S$ is closed. But in option 4, given that $S$ is open. Hence option 4 is not possible.

We know that if $S$ is open then $S^c$ is closed and if $S$ is closed then $S^c$ is open.
In options 1,2,3 $d(x,S)>0$ then $x \notin S \implies x \in S^c$. How can use this information in options 1,2,3. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: well you answered 3 yourself. you have $x\in \overline{S}$ if and only if $d(x,S)=0$. same with 1, that is, if $S$ is closed and $d(x,S)>0$, then $x$ is not in $\overline{S}=S$ so it cannot be an accumulation point since closed sets contain all their accumulation points.

Comment: in option 2, again, $x$ cannot be in the closure of $S$, so it can’t be an accumulation point of $S$

Comment: Yes, 1 and 3 are correct. Also 4 is not correct. But I could not use connectedness.

Comment: ? i have made a comment about number two. and it has been addressed in an answer. i don’t see why connectedness is relevant here

Answer (score 1):

You're right to reject option 4, but your logic for doing so could be more clear. From what you've written, it seems like you're noting that it would be true if "closed" were substituted for "open", and then concluding (fallaciously) that it therefore can't also be true for open sets. A good way to conclude that option 4 is false would be with a counterexample (e.g. try showing that, if $S = (0, 1) \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, then $d(0, S) = 0$).

Both 1 and 2 are true, simply because "open" and "closed" are irrelevant. If $d(x, S) > 0$, then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$. If it were, then there would have to be a point $y \in S$ such that $d(x, y) < d(x, S)$ (there would have to be points in $S$ that are closer than any positive quantity). Hopefully you can see why this violates the definition of $d(x, S)$.

Option 3 was answered in the comments.